# Where is Sogoria and/or Isseni located in The Hyborian Age?

Tags: conan, geography, red-sonja

I'm currently reading the "**[Queen Sonja](https://www.dynamite.com/htmlfiles/viewProduct.html?CAT=DF-Queen_Sonja)**" series of comics (by Dynamite, running from 2010–2012), which depicts Sonja's time on the throne of Sogoria. She rules from the capital city, which is called "Isseni". The comic mentions other locations, such as "Kamala, near the Sogorian Border", as well as "Emora", a neighboring kingdom that invades Sogoria prior to the story's beginning.

The trouble is, when looking at maps of Hyboria, I can't find the mentioned locations. I don't see any kingdoms called Sogoria, Kamala, or Emora. A character describing the invaders from Emora stated that they conquered Pah-Disha first... but Pah-Disha is a city in Hyrkania where Sonja's originally from.

I'm mostly a Conan fan, so I'm not that familiar with Red Sonja's part of the world (the eastern lands). **Can someone tell me, in relation to Aquilonia or Cimmeria, where Sogoria is located on a map of Hyboria? Is it somewhere inside or near Hyrkania?**

---

**Note:** I've Googled several different maps of the continent but haven't found what I'm looking for on any on them. Perhaps it's a small city-state that isn't worth showing on the map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this *Hyborian Atlas*:

[image: Hyborian Atlas cover]

> SOGARIA  This large, walled city-state, renowned for its fabrics woven from Khitian silk, is the westernmost of the Hyrkanian cities lying on the Silk Road caravan route.  The city is covered with many gorgeous flower gardens and flowing fountains.

(Sites describing the comic book series seem to agree that the spelling of the city in the comics is indeed "Sogaria.")

None of the other mysterious place names appear in this Atlas (although there are actually multiple variants of "Kamala" under different spellings).  In any case, I wouldn't put too much trust in any of this.  There is no canon of the Hyborian Age except for what was written by Robert E. Howard, and works by many authors contradict each other.  Even the earliest writers who expanded on Howard's work, Lin Carter and L. Sprague de Camp, misunderstood elements of it (not realizing, for example, that [Hyrkania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyrcania) was a real place).  Many subsequent creators have added additional places to the map, sometimes using the names of real locations—such as Sogaria, which is an obscure town in Rajasthan, India.

Comment: I'll accept that - it's about what I figured, anyway. Even within the "Queen Sonja" comic alone, the name of the place is spelled "Sogaria" in some spots and "Sogoria" in others, so I don't think fact-checking was a high priority for the writers.

Answer (score -1):

when your read the entire run, it seems like hyrkania is not a united kingdom.
Sogoria is one of the south kingom ok hyrkania and the empire cover all the south kingdom of the land. the last part of the run is the unification of hyrkania under one crown.
(yoou can see a map of hyrkania in the 4th book with all the kingdom)

Comment: This answer is very long on assertion, but offers no proof. Can you back this up with text quotes or screenshots?